# How to split string at the last occurence of a character so that the resultset contains both values?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to use reg_split to explode a string from the last occurance of a slash.

So the input `'/some/string/foo/bar/13'` shall become `['/some/string/foo/bar', 13]`

I know I can use `preg_split("/\//", $input);`, yet this splits into an array of size 6 with all the strings.

I also can match each part I want with `preg_match` like so:

```
$match = [];
$value = $page->value;
preg_match("/.*[^\d]/", $value, $match);
$base = $match[0]; // => 13

$match = [];
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $value, $match);
$numbers[] = $match[0]; // => /some/string/foo/bar
```

Yet how can I turn this into an oneline using `preg_split`? As when I try applying those `preg_match` patterns, I get an array of size 2, yet only having the value it matches and not both.

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead.

```
preg_split('~/(?=[^/]*$)~', $input);
```

or

Negative lookahead.

```
preg_split('~/(?!.*/)~', $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer to [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378732/710099), in case you want to match and capture (instead of splitting) you can also use a regex like this:

```
(.*/)(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM6vL5/1)**

Php code

```
$re = "@(.*/)(.*)@"; 
$str = "/some/string/foo/bar/13"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-21]  `/some/string/foo/bar/`
2.  [21-23] `13`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that too:

```
$str = '/some/string/foo/bar/13';

if (false !== $slashPos = strrpos($str, '/')) {
    $result = [substr($str, 0, $slashPos), substr($str, $slashPos + 1)];
    print_r($result);
}
```

or:

```
$parts = explode('/', $str);

$last = array_pop($parts);

$result = [implode('/', $parts), $last];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a oneliner, but no regex needed!

```
$input = '/some/string/foo/bar/13';
$slash_position = strrpos($input, '/');
$result = array(substr($input, 0, $slash_position), substr($input, $slash_position+1));
```

Result: `Array ( [0] => /some/string/foo/bar [1] => 13 )`